# How can I display the logged in users' name in Angular? (With token authentication)

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, token, angular6

i have been following following tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viX4IqaO3iU&index=22&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg2RBz6UplKTGIXREj9dV0G ) which I got the code below. I gained a good understanding about the concept but my question is: here I am sending back the token from the back-end, but how do I get the information about current logged in user to display in the frontend? Like what purchases he/she already did, etc. That shouldnt be all in the JWT payload, right? How can I achieve this?

thanks in advance

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
let userData = req.body

User.findOne({
    email: userData.email }, (error, user) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        if(!user){
            res.status(401).send('Invalid email')
        } else {
            if (user.password !== userData.password){
                res.status(401).send('Invalid password', invalidPass = true)
            } else {
                let payload =  { subject : User._id}
                let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey')
                res.status(200).send({token})
            }
        }
    }
})
})
```

Comment: You seem to ask two different questions: in the title you ask about user name and in the question itself you talk about purchases. And what exactly do you want to know? Where to get the information? How to decode it from the token?

Comment: @jps thats actually right, excuses for that, what I really want to know is firstly, how user-bound data, like what purchases he or she has done in the past, should go in the communication. Should that all be going in the payload of the JWT? Should I make angular models for the data? Or should i be fine without those. And secondly, indeed, what the best way is to display that data on the frontend.